# How can I get progress for loading Angular LazyModule file?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to figure out how can I made progress indication for loading Angular LazyLoaded Modules.

[image]

I can change preloading strategy but is there a hook somewhere to subscribe to loading progress?

```
export class MyPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
        return of(true).pipe(flatMap(_ => load()));
    }
}
```

is it possible to subscribe to `load` at least to know when it was loaded?

Comment: Usually, for most things, the module should not take that long to load. What you wait for it the service call to retrieve the data that is shown in that module. Do you have your data services built out separate as observables that you subscribe to? If so, perhaps your loaders could be tied to those.

Comment: "not take that long to load" - true, I'm doing it more for educational purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to `Router.events` https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events

> **RouteConfigLoadStart**
>
> An event triggered before the Router lazy loads a route configuration.
>
> **RouteConfigLoadEnd**
>
> An event triggered after a route has been lazy loaded.

Let's say you have the following lazy route:

```
{
  path: 'lazy', loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
}
```

And here's how you can hook to loading process of this module:

```
import { RouteConfigLoadEnd, RouteConfigLoadStart, Router } from '@angular/router';

...
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe((
    event => {
      if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart && event.route.path === 'lazy') {
        console.log('START');
      }
      if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd && event.route.path === 'lazy') {
        console.log('FINISH');
      }
    }));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. maybe you know the way how I can track file load progress? like overwriting/extending `NgModuleFactoryLoader`

Comment: Overriding NgModuleFactoryLoader will only help if you use loadChildren as a string. All lazy loading module are controller by RouterConfigLoader https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/72ecc453639eae017f75653c9004adc406ed2ee6/packages/router/src/router_config_loader.ts#L21-L59 And it includes onLoadStartListener and onLoadEndListener, actually these are hooks I'm subscribing to in my example. Even if you will use `loadChildren: 'stringPathToModule'` and override NgModuleFactoryLoader you will end up with exactly the same hooks: 1) when it's started and 2) when it's finished

Comment: Under the hood webpack does the following `var script = document.createElement('script');script.onload = onScriptComplete;document.head.appendChild(script)`